# Delete Row in a Column if Length of Cell not meets condition

Tags: excel, vba, row

Im working in a code in excel vba, to delete the rows if length value of a cell is not equal to 10

Im trying to avoid using filters bcause im using a file that contains like 1 millions of rows, and when using filters, the excel crash it.

this is what I need

For exemple

The Column A contain an ID numbers,

but if the length cell with the ID is not 10 characters

I want to delete the row, this row I doesn't need it

I searched around the forums and gathered some codes to create the following code

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim LR As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets(2)

    LR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 2 To LR
        For Each c In sht.Range("A2:A" & LR).Cells
            If Len(c.Value) <> 10 Then
                c.EntireRow.Delete
            End If                              '<---------here is the error
        Next
    Next

    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

when the macro is running it get stuck, I have to press **ESC** to stop the macro and the error appears in the line **End If**

This macro delete the rows that are not meeting the condition of length when I press the **ESC** button

Is there a solution in this code?
or exist  better metod to delete rows without using the filters?

Comment: You do not need two loops to do this.  Do `For i = LR to 2 Step -1` and then `If Len(sht.cells(i,1).value)<>10 then` and `sht.Rows(i).delete`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're deleting rows you should really be counting upward, since it will mess your count up. For example, i is on row 3 and then deletes row 3, now row 4 is in row 3, and i is going to continue on what used to be row 5. So instead work your way from the bottom up.

```
Sub DeleteRows()
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sht As Worksheet

    Set sht = Worksheets(2)

    LR = sht.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = LR to 2 Step -1
        If Len(sht.cells(i,1).value)<>10 then
            sht.Rows(i).delete
        End If
    Next

Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```